# UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION -, portal account owner must have a role In Test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I have a class where i have created portal user. when i am testing the functionality it works fine.
Problem occurs when writing a test class -

[image]

When writring the test class for business class method of portal user creation. its giving me the error.

Error -

[image]

Thanks

Your Reply will Highly appreciated

Comment: @Ratan What should be the query for userrole and code snippet ?

Comment: The Above mentioned query is not working.

Comment: ahh I didn't noticed you are not assigning AccountId to contact

Comment: Same here. i updated and then it works fine.

Comment: ahh I didn't noticed you are not assigning AccountId to contact .... Maha is correcty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you linked the contact to the specific account in your code before calling method to create portal user?

I couldn't see contact linked with Account in your test method.

Add one more line in the code which inserts contact.

```
con.Accountid = acc.Id;
```

Please try.Hope that solves the issue!